# Dyanmically shift to next line if size is more than parent

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to make a component which has a list of links horizontally. If the word inside the link is too long i want the entire word to move to the next line instead of just part of the word.

Below is an image of the component I've done so far. The links break midway or sometimes go out of the parent element.

[image: Problem image]

As you can see the "Mind and Soul" word is breaking midway while "Must Go Places" is going beyond the scope of the parent.

***SCSS/***

```
.sidebar-widget {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #eff4f9;
  padding: 60px 25px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;

  h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: $primary-color;

    @media #{$breakpoint-xs} {
      font-size: 24px;
    }
  }

  .sub-category-item {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;

    a {
      font-weight: 700;
      color: $secondary-color;
      padding: 2px;
    }
    margin-right: 20px;
  }

}
```

***HTML***

```
<div className="sidebar-widget">
    <h3>Sub Categories</h3>
    <span className="sub-category-item">
        <a href="#"> Random words </a>
     </span
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`display:inline-block` 
for the element or you can put all of the child elements in a container with

```
display:flex; 
flex-wrap:wrap;
```